# parsing json without knowing the identifiers in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON payload from a REST service that looks something like this:

```
var jsonify = JSON.stringify(theReturnedData);

console.log(jsonify) = 
{
    "f-012839": {
          "name": "Bob",
          "email": "asdf@gmail.com"
     }
}
```

How do I access, for example, the email value without knowing what "f-012839" is?

Here is what I have tried so far without success:

```
var name = jsonify[0].name;
var name = jsonify.name;
```

The "f-012839" value is dynamic and I won't know what it is beforehand. It'd be nice if I could get to the "name" and "email" elements without having to know what the "f-012839" key would be. Or, is it possible to take a subset of the returned JSON, so that instead of having the above value, it could be something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "email": "asdf@gmail.com"
}
```

If that's possible, I should be able to get any of those values by simply doing the below, right?

```
var name = jsonify.name;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks SO!

Comment: why are you stringyfying it?

Comment: Hey juvian, the server returns a javascript object so im stringifying it to turn it into JSON. Sorry I should have made that more clear.

Comment: To traverse the object it needs to be a javascript object, not a string. If the server is already returning an object, thats already fine. If not, you need to use JSON.parse(jsonString)

Comment: @IsaiahLee Why do you need to turn it into JSON? JSON is only needed when sending something over the network. When you want to access parts of it, you want the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(var key in theReturnedData) {
  theReturnedData[key] // This is the object you want access to
}
```

**Update** Also make sure to implement a check for each key. You need to filter out the properties that could be inherited from the objects Prototype (lots of frameworks add custom properties to object Prototypes. You can check that through Object.hasOwnProperty(property_name), so basically use this loop:

```
for(var key in theReturnedData) {
  if(!theReturnedData.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
  theReturnedData[key]
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be fair to mention, that `jsonify` has to be parsed to an object before using this code.

Comment: @Teemu, indeed i was a little confused by the stringify part and thought OP knows that with "data" i meant the "theReturnedData". Going to edit my answer.

Comment: The fact that he's stringifying it in the first place implies that he doesn't understand what he's doing.

Comment: Thanks wiesion. @Barmar, yes, I'm a noobie but I won't be making this same mistake again. Thanks everyone I completely understand it now. I'll be marking this as the answer when I can.

Comment: @IsaiahLee Thanks, i also updated the answer so you wouldn't run into trouble with undesired keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(field in JSON.parse(jsonify)) {
      firstObject = jsonify[field];
      console.log(firstObject.name);
      console.log(firstObject.email);
   }
```

Comment: It should be `JSON.parse(jsonify)` or `for (field in theReturnedData)`.